# How get timestamp on the file inside the gzip in Java

Tags: java, gzip, compression

I would like to preserve the timestamp of the file that is extracted from a gzip file in Java.

Here's the code:

```
   public void gunzipFile(String zipFile, String newFile) {
    System.out.println("zipFile: " + zipFile);
    final int bufferSize = 1024;
    try {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(zipFile);
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
        GZIPInputStream gis = new GZIPInputStream(bis);
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(newFile);
        final byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
        int len = 0;
        while ((len = gis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            fos.write(buffer, 0, len);
        }
        //close resources
        fos.close();
        gis.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("exception caught");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a hacky solution because the `GZIPInputStream` class cannot give you the timestamp.

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(zipFile);
byte[] header = new byte[10];
fis.read(header);
        
int timestamp = header[4] & 0xFF |
            (header[5] & 0xFF) << 8 |
            (header[6] & 0xFF) << 16 |
            (header[7] & 0xFF) << 24; 

// or more simply, use
// int timestamp = ByteBuffer.wrap(header, 4, 4).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).getInt();

System.out.println(new Date((long) timestamp * 1000)); // this will give you the date
```

The [GZIP format](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1952#page-4) uses a 10 byte header for some metadata. Bytes 5 (offset 4) through 8 represent the unix timestamp. If you convert those into an `int` and multiply by 1000 to get milliseconds, you can get the date of the file within (if there originally was one).

The format is (from [RFC 1952](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1952#page-4))

```
    0        1
+--------+--------+
|00001000|00000010|
+--------+--------+
 ^        ^
 |        |
 |        + more significant byte = 2 x 256
 + less significant byte = 8
```

In other words, the first byte is the last 8 bits of the `int`. That's where the `LITTLE_ENDIAN` comes in.

I would recommend you are careful using the `InputStream` here. Possibly use `BufferedInputStream` and `reset()` to position `0` or just open a different `InputStream`. Use one to get the timestamp and use the other inflate the gzip content.